# Display inline-block element with responsive image inside gets incorrect width once placed inside a absolute/fixed container in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

The title says it all. I have an image with `height: 100%` inside each of a couple `display: inline-block` `<li>` elements. When their container is `position: static`. All is peachy. But when I change it to `position: absolute/fixed`, the `<li>` elements get width of the original image, not the scaled down width even though the image itself has correct dimensions.

This behaves as expected in Chrome, but breaks in Firefox.

Did anyone encounter this behaviour? More importantly, is it possible to fix it without JS?

Background: I am making a responsive `position: fixed` gallery that fits the screen with image thumbnails covering bottom 20% of the viewport.

Isolated Demo (click the button to toggle position: static/fixed ):
http://jsfiddle.net/TomasReichmann/c93Xk/

Whole gallery
http://jsfiddle.net/TomasReichmann/c93Xk/2/

Comment: Try giving everything up the DOM tree `height:100%`, starting with the `<ul>`. Firefox doesn't understand 100% of what, so it needs to be 100% of 100% of 100%....all the way to the `html` element itself, which also should have `height:100%`

Comment: All ancestors except HTML and BODY have explicit height in percent. I tried giving body and html 100%, no change. I fixed it with JS at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. It seems that when you declare something with
`Position:fixed, left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;`
Only chrome recognizes that as "explicitly defined dimensions". Once I added height: 100%; Other browsers caught up. Fortunately the `height 100%` didn't break the layout even when the content underneath overflowed viewport.

http://jsfiddle.net/c93Xk/3/

It still breaks uniformily across all browsers when you try to resize the window. I guess, I'll have to calculate the widths by hand with JS

Answer (score 0):

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/c93Xk/1/)**

Check the demo, is that what you are looking for?

I have added these 2 lines of css to make it work like that:

```
/* Keep Position fixed at bottom */
#gallery:not(.toggle) { width: 100%; bottom: 0; top: auto; height: 20%; background: transparent; }
#gallery:not(.toggle) .gallery-thumbs{ height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Wow, how did you do that? There is a problem though. The gallery should fill the viewport. I supplied another demo with the whole gallery, not only thumbnails. Can you make it work with the full gallery?

Comment: your new demo is quite a challenge :p

Comment: Yeah well, I spent a lot of time on this myself. When I was out of ideas, I submitted it here :-/

I don't even know why it does that. It's ok in Chrome ...

It might have something to do with declaring width. The width of IMG tag is calculated when the LI is already in place. The browser makes a guess about the LIs width, but doesn't update it once the IMG is in place. Not even when I fiddle around after it has been rendered. I am out of ideas :-/